# Spring Boot Shutdown with Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-scheduled

I'm using Spring Boot + Spring Task Scheduler to creating a polling application.  I plan to use the actuator to shutdown the application during maintenance windows (see shutdown endpoint for actuator: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints).

My question is, will the Spring be smart enough finish an in-flight task before gracefully shutting down the application?  Will Spring be smart enough not to start another task if the in-flight task completes before shutdown?

Thank you.

Comment: I know that shutdown waits 60 (millis?) by default before shutting down the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this by setting

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown
```

to true.

There is a really good explanation in the javadoc of the inherited setter

```
org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport#setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown
```

> Set whether to wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown,
>       not interrupting running tasks and executing all tasks in the queue.
>
> Default is "false", shutting down immediately through interrupting
>       ongoing tasks and clearing the queue. Switch this flag to "true" if you
>        prefer fully completed tasks at the expense of a longer shutdown phase...

The spring scheduler uses per default a

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
```

which will not start new tasks during shutdown as described in javadoc of

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#shutdown
```

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted
>      tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted...

Answer (score 5):

Since spring boot 2.1 you can set the following property

```
# Whether to wait for running jobs to complete on shutdown.
spring.quartz.wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown=false
```

Comment: This is the default value so nothing is there to set.

Comment: This is for Quartz implementation only. The application can rely on another scheduler implementation.